# Wait until all iOS blocks are executed before moving on

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a data model/store object that interfaces with the Internet over several APIs containing data. The number of APIs to be interfaced with is dynamic: from a conceptual standpoint, we can consider the endpoints to be strings in an NSMutableArray. The issue is that I want to notify views/other observers of updated data after the *last* endpoint/API call is completed. I tried GCD dispatch but the following pattern doesn't seem to work properly:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{

    for(MyAPIEndpoint __weak __block *ep in apiList)
    {

       [self runAPI:ep withCompletionBlock:^(MyAPIEndpoint *api, NSError *err)
       {
           // update the data model here, code omitted as it's not relevant
       }
       ];
    }
});

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

// this statement must only execute AFTER the last block in the for loop above is done
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"apiDataUpdated" object:self];
```

However, it doesn't seem to work; it seems the code inside that [self runAPI...] call is never executed at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played around with dispatch groups the other day, here is a really helpful [blog post](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/) by [jrturton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/852828/jrturton) which should help you with the basics!

But basically it looks like your missing the line to enter/leave the dispatch group. So non of your `runAPI` methods are being run as you have no items in the group and `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"apiDataUpdated" object:self];` gets called straight away.

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

for(MyAPIEndpoint __weak __block *ep in apiList)
{
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [self runAPI:ep withCompletionBlock:^(MyAPIEndpoint *api, NSError *err)
    {
        // update the data model here, code omitted as it's not relevant
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];
}
});

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"apiDataUpdated" object:self];
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Rich, let me try it!

Comment: Sorry I've mixed and matched code and not taken some code out from your question, let me edit the answer with a complete implementation!

Comment: I figured that was the case. ;) Really appreciate both the fast answer and the code update! I think it's working now.